# Unknown Bytes error in uploading a Video file

Tags: upload

I am having my site hosted in Bluehost server. I have been working with the Allvideos Plugin to have the video inside article content. When i try to upload my video my filename.flv in the folder/images/stories/videos/ , i am getting the error as Business Agility_VS.flv: unknown Bytes: 0% Complete FAILED! :Unknown error or disk quota exceeded.

What may be the problem in this??

Even i have increased the size of the destination folder. But still i am getting this error. Why i am getting the Unknown Bytes error.